# MERGE INSERT Source.*

Tags: sql-server, merge, implicit-conversion

Currently we have a SQL script to upsert configuration settings.

```
MERGE [dbo].[ConfigurationSetting] AS Target
USING (SELECT * FROM (VALUES 
    -- <Snip> Hard-coded rows.
) AS s([Id], [Key], [DisplayName], [Value])) AS Source
    ON Target.[Id] = Source.[Id]
WHEN MATCHED THEN
    UPDATE SET
        [Key] = Source.[Key],
        [DisplayName] = Source.[DisplayName]
        -- Preserve existing [Value]
WHEN NOT MATCHED BY TARGET THEN 
    INSERT ([Id], [Key], [DisplayName], [Value])
    VALUES (Source.[Id], Source.[Key], Source.[DisplayName], Source.[Value])
WHEN NOT MATCHED BY SOURCE THEN
    DELETE
;
```

This works fine, but just for my desire for simplicity, is there a syntax that can simplify the
`INSERT ... VALUES ...` clauses to something resembling `INSERT VALUES Source.*`

Answer (score 0):

Your idea of simplicity is actually absurdity.
Using `" * "` is itself bad idea from performance point of view.

Secondly suppose tomorrow table design is altered  with computed column or default value then INSERT VALUES Source.* may not work at all or may give wrong result.

Most importantly it is not possible.

Or you can remove Merge and use separate insert and update .Then you can do what you want